# Add files programmatically to Order in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the "woocommerce_order_status_completed" hook to create a file dynamically after the user has paid for the order. 
I need to add this file to his downloadable area in that order in this hooks.

Any ideias how to attach a file to a order?

Answer (score 2):

woocommerce_order_status_completed you can add below code...
First store the file you have created in uploads using [media_handle_upload](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload)

```
if($_FILES){
//if u don't want to $post_id u gan give 0
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'abe_update_epub', $post_id );
if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
    $errors = $attachment_id->get_error_messages();
    foreach( $errors as $error ){
        echo $error;
    }
    echo 'There was an error uploading the image';
} else {
    // NEW FILE: Setting the name, getting the url and and Md5 hash number
    $file_name = 'Epub Files';
    $file_url  = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
    $md5_num = md5( $file_url );

    // Inserting new file in downloadable files
    $files[$md5_num] = array(
        'name' => $file_name,
        'file' => $file_url
    );

    // Updating database with the new array


    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    if(!empty($files)){
        update_post_meta($order->ID,_files,$files));
    }
    // Displaying a success notice
    echo 'The image was uploaded successfully!';
}
}
```

Hopes this help u..

Comment: Yay, it helped me a lot! But I was thinking about attaching a file to the order.
If I attach it to the product, other users will see it too.
My store creates the virtual file dynamically after the user choose a date range, and I needed to attach it to the ORDER itself, not the product

Comment: By order I mean this:
[link](http://i.imgur.com/Jz5VA3r.png)

I want to attach a file to the whole Order, not just a product.
So depending on the products the user buys, it will generate a file based on that, and be attached to that particular order.

Comment: I edited my answer...hope this will help you.. please upvote if it helps...thank you

Comment: Nice approach! It worked for me now that I can relate files to an order!
Now I Just have to work on something that can make any type of files in the media library downloadable. I have some .csv files that I attached to the order, and I can't download them :(

Comment: Sry u have to download from order page itself..?